# Flutter: How to keep Podfile.lock in sync when working in a team

Tags: flutter, cocoapods

I am working on a Flutter project (Android+iOS) in a team and it seems we are having difficulties keeping the Podfile.lock in sync with each other.

Whenever one does a "flutter clean" and then tries do build we get errors that forces the one currently trying to build to do a "pod update" (a "flutter pub get" followed by a "pod install" usually does not suffice).

But then all the pods get updated and the Podfile.lock changes.

And then another developer builds the project (who has not done the pod update) and that changes the pod version (and hence the Podfile.lock) back.

That leads to a git-change-war until all developers do a "pod update" **at the same time** to get the Podfile.lock in sync again.

That cannot be the way this is supposed to be done.

What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be not to version-control your Podfile.lock file.

Comment: Hey Ayevbeosa, thx!
That is what we are doing - and that is what leads to the git-change-war.
I guess the actual problem is the fact that sometimes after a flutter clean we can only successfully make an iOS build if we do a "pod udpate". And maybe I also do not really understand the relationship between the pubpsec.yaml and the Podfile.lock. I assumed that in my pubspec.yaml I define what versions of which plugins I want to use. But it seems that while using the same version of a Flutter plugin as defined in pubspeck.yaml, the versions of the pods needed for that still can vary.

Comment: To answer your question about the relationship between the Podfile.lock file and pubspec.yaml, the Podfile.lock keeps track of the iOS specific dependencies of the plugins in the pubspec.yaml.

Comment: Yes, that much I know :) I'm just puzzled by the fact that the versions in the Podfile.lock can change without the versions in the pubspec.yaml changing. Or, to put it differently: I can "freeze" my Flutter plugins by specifying an explicit version in the pubspec.yaml, making sure that later builds will produce the same result. But the Podfile.lock can be very different on each developer's machine, even when we all use the same pubspec.yaml - resulting in different builds, depending on which machine they were built on :(

Comment: Ideally, this shouldn't be an issue, what we do is whenever we pull an update from git, we run flutter pub get and then pod install. Then we can build without a hitch, doing flutter clean seems extreme, unless there is something else causing the build errors.

Comment: Maybe the flutter clean can be avoided (I remember we had to do it or it wouldn't build) – but my main concern is that it seems that checking in the Podfile.lock and making sure everyone is using the same version of that is not enough! When I use the checked out version if the Podfile.lock and make a (successful) build, it changes the Podfile.lock back again ("COCOAPODS: 1.12.1"). If checkin that Podfile.lock and my colleague builds, the Podfile is changed back to "COCOAPODS: 1.13.0" again.

Comment: It seems that some part of the information about which version of what to use for a build is stored not in the source code (pubspec/Podfile/...) but in the system setup of each developer. That's bad...

Comment: Just so I understand correctly, is the Podfile.lock in your version control?

Comment: Yes. And whenever it changes it is committed. But the Podfile.lock does not seem to be the ground truth for which versions of which pods are to be used. If one developer has older versions of the pods installed on his/her system, when making an iOS build, the Podfile.lock gets changed back again and the old versions are put in the Podfile.lock again...

Comment: Like I said earlier, your team will have to **not** commit the Podfile.lock and remove it completely from your version control, to avoid the git issues you mentioned. So maybe try things this way.

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that this would be one way. Unfortunately that would also mean that the git repo is not the ground truth for what code actually goes into a build. Every developer can then have his/her own version of the Podfile.lock with different versions of the pods. I would like to find a different solution. But in any case: Thank you very much for your time and insight!